# Retrofit2: Why is object null if server response is OK and GSON didn't report any parsing issue?

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

[image]

Why is `price` null here?

JSON is retrieved from [here](https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin&vs_currencies=USD) (you could also use multiple parameters, that is why the below object uses `Map`s; [example](https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin,ethereum&vs_currencies=USD,EUR)). Here is `CoinGeckoCoinPrice`:

```
public class CoinGeckoCoinPrice {
    @Expose
    private Map<String, Map<String, Double>> price;

    public double getPrice(String slug, String pair) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Here is my Retrofit2 call:

```
@GET("/api/v3/simple/price")
Call<CoinGeckoCoinPrice> getCoinPrice(@Query("ids") String coinSlugs, @Query("vs_currencies") String pairs);
```

I checked logcat for any GSON error message and there is none. So why would `price` be null?

---

It works if I change Retrofit2 call to use `JsonObject`:

```
@GET("/api/v3/simple/price")
Call<JsonObject> getCoinPrice(@Query("ids") String coinSlugs, @Query("vs_currencies") String pairs);
```

But I want to wrap the object so I can write data retrieval functions in the `CoinGeckoCoinPrice` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Json you are getting back doesn't have a `price` property on it, so Gson doesn't know that it should be parsing the `bitcoin` object and its price in USD to that object. Given that your returned data can be for any key (i.e. bitcoin, ethereum...) and its properties can also have any keys (i.e. usd, euros...) you'll need to manually parse this by giving Gson a custom adapter to work with.